# Report Data disappearing when parameter Refresh

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have an `ssrs` report with multiple `parameters` ( region, district, office ).
The issue here is, whenever  a `parameter` value is `refreshed`, report data also changed (`vanished`) before clicking `view report button`. is it a default 
behavior? is there any way to retain the report data during p`arameter refresh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to change the way the parameter update works.

I think it works that way by default so that the report isn't displaying data from a previously run report to avoid confusion when changing the parameters.

Otherwise a user might change the parameters but then get distracted before clicking **View**. Then when the user returns to the report, there is data. If the data isn't removed, they might think the data is from the current parameters.

What are you trying to accomplish with this? If you want users to see some data to make their parameter choices, you might need to make your parameters better with cascading parameters, adding more information to the parameter's drop down menu, sorting them with the highest amount first or making better default values.

Comment: the parameters are cascading only. I felt that the vanishing of the entire report data with the data refresh might not be a great option in users point of view